# Reaction of chlorine with hot/cold solution of hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

When chlorine reacts with cold solution of say potasium hydroxide, the disproportionation goes to lower oxidation states:

$\ce{Cl2 + 2 KOH -> KCl + KClO + H2O} $

Whilst with hot solution the oxidation state of chlorine goes up to $+V$:

$\ce{3 Cl2 + 6 KOH -> KClO3 + 5 KCl + 3 H2O} $

Why is that? Does the heat make the oxidation to higher ox. states easier?

Comment: Heat makes pretty much _everything_ easier.

Answer (score -1):

The chlorate ($\ce{ClO3-}$) is formed by disproportionation of hypochlorite and hypochlorous acid:

$$\ce{ClO- + 2 HClO -> ClO3- + 2 HCl}$$

Higher temperature promotes the formation of hypochlorous acid through hydrolysis of hypochlorite and therefore speeds up the reaction.

Comment: I am afriad this answer is incorrect. There is no hypochlorous acid in a highly alkaline medium.

Comment: Additionally and generally, reactions in highly alkaline medium are not written in the way producing strong acid, furthermore not even ionized even if the equation takes the ionic form.

Comment: This is how the reaction is described in literature. The mechanism involves dissociation of HClO into hydroxyl and chlorine radicals. Note that hypochloric acid is a very weak acid and that this fact and increased temperature can very well lead to the formation of enough HClO to enable the reaction, even in very alkaline solutions. Of course you are free to balance out the reaction in a way that emphasizes more on educts and product of the reaction.